# Visualize a variable in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, printf, visualize

Hi I'm using action scrit 3 and I need to visualize on the movie that I'm making one data stored on an integer variable. What I want to do is something similar to "trace" in flash but in the movie that I'm making.
The definition for the variable is:

```
var num_preguntas:Number;
```

How can I print this number in a photogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a dynamic textfield on the stage (or reference one already there) and then write the number to that textfield. So something like:

```
var tf:TextField = new TextField();
tf.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
tf.text = num_preguntas.toString();
addChild(tf);
```